# Asus k52f memory upgrade

Tags: laptop, memory, compatibility, upgrade

Consider the following configuration:

- Asus K52f notebook with
- Mobile Dual Core Intel Pentium P6100, 2000 MHz (15 x 133)
- chipset: Intel Ibex Peak-M HM55, Intel Ironlake-M
- "2GB DDR3-1333 SDRAM (10-9-9-24 @ 666 MHz) (9-9-9-24..." - all these data are from an Aida64 screenshot
- the memory module, physically, has 8 memory chips on each side (16 chips in total). From a google search, it seems to be an ASint SSZ3128M8-EDJEF 2GB module 2Rx8 PC3-10600 1333MHz

Questions:

1. Would a 2GB 1333MHz Samsung M471B5773DH0-CH9 ddr3 module be compatible with the above configuration? (so that it ends up with 2 sticks of memory: Asint+Samsung)
2. Do you think there will be memory incompatibilities due to ranking: his memory seems to be 2Rx8 (that's what I found on internet), while the Samsung is 1Rx8
3. could you recommend a forum/site where I could check any memory with any mainboard (there are some RAM producers which say whether *their* memory module are compatible with some notebooks, but I hadn't found something like this for Samsung or Asus)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I bought the Samsung memory, tried the configuration and it works.

Maybe others might find the following answers useful, but I can NOT guarantee it's going to work on you specific configuration too:

1. since the memory modules have similar characteristics (CAS latency, ddr3 speed and voltage) there is high probability for them to work together.
2. I'd tested the configuration and there are no ranking incompatibilities.
3. unfortunately, I don't think somebody had time to test all the possible combinations of memories on all possible mainboards.